# Combining multiple binary files into a single file using Powershell

Tags: powershell, copy, binaryfiles

I have an existing Batch script that I need to rewrite as a Powershell script.  However, it contains the following command that doesn't seem to have a Powershell equivalent.

```
copy *.0* /b output.bin
```

Is there a simpler way to do this than 'manually' iterating over each block of data in every file using `[IO.File]::OpenRead()` and appending it to the output?

Note that executing the copy command using `cmd /c` is not an option.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (I'm asking innocently): Why is `cmd /c` not an option?

Comment: The command prompt will be disabled which is why I can't use a batch script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a chunked approach via the `-AsByteStream` (PowerShell (Core) 7+) / `-Encoding Byte` (Windows PowerShell) parameter of the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlets:

```sh
# Read the raw bytes in 64MB chunks across all matching input files
# and save to a single output file.
# Note: In Windows PowerShell, replace -AsByteStream with -Encoding Byte
Get-Content -ReadCount 64mb -AsByteStream *.0* |
  Set-Content -AsByteStream output.bin
```

Note:

- Increase the chunk size passed to `-ReadCount` to speed up the operation, memory permitting (`64mb` is just a sample value).

  - If you're confident that the bytes making up the largest among the input files fit into memory *as a whole* (as a `[byte[]]` array), you can use `-Raw` instead of `-ReadCount $n` for the best performance.
- Without `-ReadCount`, the bytes stream *one by one*, which is very slow.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that explains so much! I had tried this when I had to split and re-combine binaries a while ago and it was **so slow** that I regressed to using `copy /b` instead of a native PowerShell option.